# PayPal user input form with IPN

Tags: html, paypal, user-input, paypal-ipn, form-fields

Quick question relating to PayPal's IPN and user input fields...

Is there a way for me to use data inputted in the form fields (name and email) by the user through to the IPN.

I realise there are the field names first_name, last_name and email that can be called in the IPN - however these relate to the PayPal account holder's details, not the user input.

From what I gather even if I have an input field in the form "named" first_name, its value will be overwritten by the first_name of the PayPal account holder.

I could use custom - but I need 2 of them (name and email).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could put both values into the variable for "CUSTOM", and use a separator.  Then in your IPN script, you could just parse out the values.